# Change rootViewController from uiviewcontroller to uinavigationcontroller

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uiapplicationdelegate, rootview

I am developing an app that use `MFsidemenu` for the swipeBar.
My app consists of a `loginController` which is an `uiViewController` and after logging it change into an `uiNavigationController`.

`MFsidemenu` need this code running on the AppDelegate:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;

UIViewController *leftSideMenuViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"leftSideMenuViewController"];
[MFSideMenu menuWithNavigationController:navigationController
                  leftSideMenuController:leftSideMenuViewController
                 rightSideMenuController:nil];
```

The problem is how to change the second line of the code if the initialView is an `uiViewController`(Login) and after that, how to pass it to the `secondViewController`(MainMenu) which is an `uiNavigationController`?

In a shortway, I want the `MFSidemenu` to work only on the secondController, which is the main controller. Thanks!

Updated:
solved, by SpaceDust solution below :)

Question Update:
So the example of using `MFSidemenu` only limited to showing a sidemenu on the controller. The example `sideMenuController` exiled from any other segue on the storyboard. on the sidemenu I implemented `uiTableViewController` to navigate to another controller. So how to change MainMenuView with `sideMenuController` `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`? I hope my english good enough to represent my situation though. Thanks once again!

Comment: why dont you make your `navigationcontroller's rootviewcontroller` the `uiViewController(Login)` ?

Comment: because i dont want the swipebar work on the loginController. i want it work only on main menu which is the secondController. any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to present your `uiViewController(Login)` as a modal view controller if you dont want to side menu appear during login.

Create a login viewcontroller in storyboard, give it a storyboard id lets say LoginViewController . Dont connect that viewcontroller to anything on storyboard let it sit a corner by itself.

first create a global singleton variable where you check if user is logged in

then In your `navigationcontroller's rootviewcontroller`

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
     //this will present the login view if user is not logged in
    if (isLoggedIn==NO) {

        UIStoryboard* sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard"
                                                     bundle:nil];
        LoginViewController *loginVC = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LoginViewController"];
        [self presentModalViewController:loginVC  animated:YES];

    }
}
```

in your login viewcontroller when login process is complete
change global singleton bool to `isLoggedIn=YES` 
then dismiss your login view controller.

`[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO];`

Comment: everything works perfect man! thanks! but i stumble on another issue here. gonna update my question above. :)

Comment: @AlvinResmana to update your `mainmenuview` from tableviewcontroller you need to create a `delegate pattern method` and call it when `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, this is entirely a new question create another question for updating `mainmenuview`, dont update this question because  your problem is solved

Comment: thank you @SpaceDust. I'll create another one. sorry for updating, did not know about the rules.